# where may I add google-site-verification?

Tags: magento2, html, google

I have a html file, where and how can I add it to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add html file in pub folder and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="FOLLOWED BY CODE">
```

Add above piece of code on the following path from Magento Admin:

> Admin sidebar > Content > Design > Configuration > Edit >
> Other Settings > HTML Head >  Scripts and Style Sheets

For more details, please refer to these links: [Link-1](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/html-head.html) [Link-2](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)

Comment: I have to add html file not just code

Comment: tried this 
```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="googleaae4bd5a0f08cd63.html;url=http://dev.kopiererhaus/googleaae4bd5a0f08cd63.html">
```
  not working

Comment: Please go to Cache Management and refresh cache types if the Cache Types are invalidated. Add mentioned code in global and check again.

Comment: ofc I cleared cache, what does it mean add in global?

Comment: In the Design Configuration grid, you can see first row which is Global(This is the highest level in the Magento pyramid). After adding the data in global check "View Page Source" in browser.

Comment: ah okay. tried it but that couldn't fix